# Showdown Not Appearing in Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, showdown

I'm using the [`showdown-rails`](https://github.com/joshmcarthur/showdown-rails) gem for the first time and am having some trouble getting it to appear.  I ran through the installation of the gem as instructed on the GitHub page, including it in my `application.js` file with `//= require showdown`.  I am using it in a `_form` partial on my `wikis#edit`/`wikis#new` page using the following code:

```
<%= form_for(@wiki) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= f.label :body %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", style: "height: 250px", id: "wiki_body" %>


  <% if current_user.admin? || current_user.premium? %>
    <%= f.label :private, class: 'checkbox' do %>
      <%= f.check_box :private %> Make Wiki Private
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% if @wiki.private? %>
    <%= f.label "Add Collaborators", class: 'checkbox' %>
    <div style="height: 80px; overflow: scroll; border: thin grey solid; padding-left: 10px">
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "wiki[user_ids][]", user.id, @wiki.users.include?(user) %>
        <%= user.name %><br>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <script>
    var converter = new showdown.Converter();
    $('#wiki_body').on('keyup', function() {
      var mdown = $(this).val();
     $('#wiki_preview').html(converter.makeHtml(mdown));
    });
  </script>

  <div class="well" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <p id="wiki_preview"></p>
  </div> <!-- showdown well -->

  <div class="text-center">
    <%= f.submit "Create Wiki", class: "btn-custom" %>
  </div> <!-- text-center -->
<% end %>
```

The well appears, but the actual text `Showdown` should render never appears.  This is my first time using the gem, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Can anyone point out my error here?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is a little bit older, I had the same problem, and since there is no answer yet so I thought I'd share my result.

First, it is considered good practice to not write your JavaScript directly in your views, but you should use the corresponding files under the `assets/javascript` subdirectory, i.e. `assets/javascripts/wiki.js`.

Second, I encountered issued with rails not being able to load the imported javascript correctly with the installed version. I got `Reference Error: showdown is not defined` on my JavaScript console. Strangely enough, just running `bundle update` fixed this issue.

Third, I encountered that this code has some issues with `turbolinks`, which is activated by rails on default. Basically speaking, you need to make sure that your script will be loaded after turbolinks has set up the page. You ensure this by inserting `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()` before your function, in your case

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var converter = new showdown.Converter();
    $('#wiki_body').on('keyup', function() {
        var mdown = $(this).val();
     $('#wiki_preview').html(converter.makeHtml(mdown));
    });
}
```

You can check if turbolinks are activated in your `views/layouts/application.html.erb` file, if turbolinks is activated you'll have a line saying `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>`